# Magento 2 cache_invalidate loop

Tags: magento2, cache, varnish

I've got a problem on one of our Magento 2.1.6 shops. Sometimes the log fills with hundereds/thousands of cache_invalidate entries.

```
[2017-06-28 14:05:26] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"https://magento2.local/woonkamer/vloerkleden?p=2&isAjax=1","invalidateInfo":{"servers":["[object] (Zend\\Uri\\Uri: http://1.1.1.1:8080/)"],"tagsPattern":"((^|,)rewards_purchase_1425(,|$))"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-06-28 14:05:26] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"https://magento2.local/woonkamer/vloerkleden?isAjax=1","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["rewards_purchase"],"mode":"matchingAnyTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-06-28 14:05:26] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"https://magento2.local/woonkamer/vloerkleden?isAjax=1","invalidateInfo":{"servers":["[object] (Zend\\Uri\\Uri: http://1.1.1.1:8080/)"],"tagsPattern":"((^|,)rewards_purchase_1425(,|$))"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-06-28 14:05:26] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"https://magento2.local/woonkamer/vloerkleden?isAjax=1","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["rewards_purchase"],"mode":"matchingAnyTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-06-28 14:05:26] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"https://magento2.local/woonkamer/vloerkleden?isAjax=1","invalidateInfo":{"servers":["[object] (Zend\\Uri\\Uri: http://1.1.1.1:8080/)"],"tagsPattern":"((^|,)rewards_purchase_1425(,|$))"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-06-28 14:05:26] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"https://magento2.local/woonkamer/vloerkleden?p=2&isAjax=1","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["rewards_purchase"],"mode":"matchingAnyTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-06-28 14:05:26] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"https://magento2.local/woonkamer/vloerkleden?p=2&isAjax=1","invalidateInfo":{"servers":["[object] (Zend\\Uri\\Uri: http://1.1.1.1:8080/)"],"tagsPattern":"((^|,)rewards_purchase_1425(,|$))"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-06-28 14:05:26] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"https://magento2.local/woonkamer/vloerkleden?p=2&isAjax=1","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["rewards_purchase"],"mode":"matchingAnyTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-06-28 14:05:26] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"https://magento2.local/woonkamer/vloerkleden?p=2&isAjax=1","invalidateInfo":{"servers":["[object] (Zend\\Uri\\Uri: http://1.1.1.1:8080/)"],"tagsPattern":"((^|,)rewards_purchase_1425(,|$))"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-06-28 14:05:26] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"https://magento2.local/woonkamer/vloerkleden?p=2&isAjax=1","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["rewards_purchase"],"mode":"matchingAnyTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-06-28 14:05:26] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"https://magento2.local/woonkamer/vloerkleden?p=2&isAjax=1","invalidateInfo":{"servers":["[object] (Zend\\Uri\\Uri: http://1.1.1.1:8080/)"],"tagsPattern":"((^|,)rewards_purchase_1425(,|$))"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-06-28 14:05:26] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"https://magento2.local/customer/section/load/?sections=cart&update_section_id=false&_=1498658171071","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["rewards_purchase"],"mode":"matchingAnyTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-06-28 14:05:26] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"https://magento2.local/customer/section/load/?sections=cart&update_section_id=false&_=1498658171071","invalidateInfo":{"servers":["[object] (Zend\\Uri\\Uri: http://1.1.1.1:8080/)"],"tagsPattern":"((^|,)rewards_purchase_1425(,|$))"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-06-28 14:05:26] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"https://magento2.local/woonkamer/vloerkleden?isAjax=1","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["rewards_purchase"],"mode":"matchingAnyTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-06-28 14:05:26] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"https://magento2.local/woonkamer/vloerkleden?isAjax=1","invalidateInfo":{"servers":["[object] (Zend\\Uri\\Uri: http://1.1.1.1:8080/)"],"tagsPattern":"((^|,)rewards_purchase_1425(,|$))"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-06-28 14:05:26] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"https://magento2.local/woonkamer/vloerkleden?isAjax=1","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["rewards_purchase"],"mode":"matchingAnyTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-06-28 14:05:26] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"https://magento2.local/woonkamer/vloerkleden?isAjax=1","invalidateInfo":{"servers":["[object] (Zend\\Uri\\Uri: http://1.1.1.1:8080/)"],"tagsPattern":"((^|,)rewards_purchase_1425(,|$))"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-06-28 14:05:26] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"https://magento2.local/woonkamer/vloerkleden?isAjax=1","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["rewards_purchase"],"mode":"matchingAnyTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-06-28 14:05:26] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"https://magento2.local/woonkamer/vloerkleden?isAjax=1","invalidateInfo":{"servers":["[object] (Zend\\Uri\\Uri: http://1.1.1.1:8080/)"],"tagsPattern":"((^|,)rewards_purchase_1425(,|$))"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-06-28 14:05:26] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"https://magento2.local/customer/section/load/?_=1498658171070","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["rewards_purchase"],"mode":"matchingAnyTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-06-28 14:05:26] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"https://magento2.local/customer/section/load/?_=1498658171070","invalidateInfo":{"servers":["[object] (Zend\\Uri\\Uri: http://1.1.1.1:8080/)"],"tagsPattern":"((^|,)rewards_purchase_1425(,|$))"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-06-28 14:05:26] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"https://magento2.local/woonkamer/vloerkleden?p=2&isAjax=1","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["rewards_purchase"],"mode":"matchingAnyTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-06-28 14:05:26] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"https://magento2.local/woonkamer/vloerkleden?p=2&isAjax=1","invalidateInfo":{"servers":["[object] (Zend\\Uri\\Uri: http://1.1.1.1:8080/)"],"tagsPattern":"((^|,)rewards_purchase_1425(,|$))"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-06-28 14:05:26] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"https://magento2.local/woonkamer/vloerkleden?p=2&isAjax=1","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["rewards_purchase"],"mode":"matchingAnyTag"},"is_exception":false} []
```

I'm running Varnish with Purging enabled.

```
 'http_cache_hosts' =>
  array (
    0 =>
    array (
      'host' => '1.1.1.1',
      'port' => '8080',
    ),
```

All the cache invalidations will crash a single dedicated server from time to time (server load 50+). What does Magento cache invalidation mean? And why does it crash the server? I'm not sure what they mean, and how I can debug this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are not errors. This simply suggest that cache has been invalidated. This debug logs are printed in following conditions -

1. If a page is opened first time i.e no cache and cache is created for first time
2. if the cache interval is ended and new cache is generated.

Refer to these links.
https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-2/Cache-invalidate/td-p/25224

Answer (score 0):

when i try to duplicate a product its magento 2.3.5 go in infinite loop, its run untill its reach max execution time, its throw me these errors?

```
    [2020-06-28 10:39:29] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"http://127.0.0.1/live/admin/catalog/product/save/id/54381/type/simple/store/0/set/17/key/349e9cd9e824f0531311b30f18fa3fe27ee6c6903b860edc951d6cede081809d/back/edit","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["catalog_product_54381"],"mode":"matchingAnyTag"}} []
[2020-06-28 10:39:30] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"http://127.0.0.1/live/admin/catalog/product/save/id/54381/type/simple/store/0/set/17/key/349e9cd9e824f0531311b30f18fa3fe27ee6c6903b860edc951d6cede081809d/back/edit","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["cat_p"],"mode":"matchingAnyTag"}} []
[2020-06-28 10:39:31] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"http://127.0.0.1/live/admin/catalog/product/save/id/54381/type/simple/store/0/set/17/key/349e9cd9e824f0531311b30f18fa3fe27ee6c6903b860edc951d6cede081809d/back/edit","invalidateInfo":{"servers":["[object] (Laminas\\Uri\\Uri: http://127.0.0.1:80/)"],"formattedTagsChunk":"((^|,)cat_p_54381(,|$))"}} []
[2020-06-28 10:39:31] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"http://127.0.0.1/live/admin/catalog/product/save/id/54381/type/simple/store/0/set/17/key/349e9cd9e824f0531311b30f18fa3fe27ee6c6903b860edc951d6cede081809d/back/edit","invalidateInfo":{"servers":["[object] (Laminas\\Uri\\Uri: http://127.0.0.1:80/)"],"formattedTagsChunk":"((^|,)cat_p_54381(,|$))"}} []
[2020-06-28 10:39:32] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"http://127.0.0.1/live/admin/catalog/product/save/id/54381/type/simple/store/0/set/17/key/349e9cd9e824f0531311b30f18fa3fe27ee6c6903b860edc951d6cede081809d/back/edit","invalidateInfo":{"servers":["[object] (Laminas\\Uri\\Uri: http://127.0.0.1:80/)"],"formattedTagsChunk":"((^|,)cat_p_54381(,|$))"}} []
[2020-06-28 10:39:37] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"http://127.0.0.1/live/admin/catalog/product/save/id/54381/type/simple/store/0/set/17/key/349e9cd9e824f0531311b30f18fa3fe27ee6c6903b860edc951d6cede081809d/back/edit","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["cat_p_54381"],"mode":"matchingAnyTag"}} []
[2020-06-28 10:39:37] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"http://127.0.0.1/live/admin/catalog/product/save/id/54381/type/simple/store/0/set/17/key/349e9cd9e824f0531311b30f18fa3fe27ee6c6903b860edc951d6cede081809d/back/edit","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["cat_p_54381"],"mode":"matchingAnyTag"}} []
[2020-06-28 10:39:37] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"http://127.0.0.1/live/admin/catalog/product/save/id/54381/type/simple/store/0/set/17/key/349e9cd9e824f0531311b30f18fa3fe27ee6c6903b860edc951d6cede081809d/back/edit","invalidateInfo":{"servers":["[object] (Laminas\\Uri\\Uri: http://127.0.0.1:80/)"],"formattedTagsChunk":"((^|,)cat_p_54381(,|$))"}} []
[2020-06-28 10:41:19] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"http://127.0.0.1/live/admin/catalog/product/save/id/54381/type/simple/store/0/set/17/key/349e9cd9e824f0531311b30f18fa3fe27ee6c6903b860edc951d6cede081809d/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["catalog_product_54381"],"mode":"matchingAnyTag"}} []
[2020-06-28 10:41:19] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"http://127.0.0.1/live/admin/catalog/product/save/id/54381/type/simple/store/0/set/17/key/349e9cd9e824f0531311b30f18fa3fe27ee6c6903b860edc951d6cede081809d/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["cat_p"],"mode":"matchingAnyTag"}} []
[2020-06-28 10:41:19] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"http://127.0.0.1/live/admin/catalog/product/save/id/54381/type/simple/store/0/set/17/key/349e9cd9e824f0531311b30f18fa3fe27ee6c6903b860edc951d6cede081809d/","invalidateInfo":{"servers":["[object] (Laminas\\Uri\\Uri: http://127.0.0.1:80/)"],"formattedTagsChunk":"((^|,)cat_p_54381(,|$))"}} []
[2020-06-28 10:41:19] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"http://127.0.0.1/live/admin/catalog/product/save/id/54381/type/simple/store/0/set/17/key/349e9cd9e824f0531311b30f18fa3fe27ee6c6903b860edc951d6cede081809d/","invalidateInfo":{"servers":["[object] (Laminas\\Uri\\Uri: http://127.0.0.1:80/)"],"formattedTagsChunk":"((^|,)cat_p_54381(,|$))"}} []
```